# Overlay toolbar with other toolbar when item is selected in RecyclerView which is inside a fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, whatsapp

To illustrate what I mean with this, it is similar to WhatsApp, where various options are displayed in the toolbar when a chat is selected.

[image]

[image]

I have a similar layout, so a MainActivity with Fragments containing RecyclerViews. Now when an item in a RecyclerView is selected I would like to get a similar behaviour as in WhatsApp. The RecyclerViews have an Adapter that implements an OnClickListener.
However, from this Adapter I do not seem to have access to Views from the MainActivity. I tried the following (inside the OnClick method in the Adapter), but it did not work since the view could not be found.

```
View view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main_activity);
if( view instanceof Toolbar) {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view;
    toolbar.setTitle("TestTitle");
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the intended behavior or have a reference to a tutorial?

**UPDATE: for who is also stuck with this and this is still quite confusing, here is how I solved it in my own words**

My Fragment contains the Interface by adding the following code to it;

```
OnItemsSelected mCallBack;

public interface OnItemsSelected {
    void onToolbarOptions(String title);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    mCallback = (OnItemsSelected) getActivity();
}
```

Also I passed 'mCallback' to the adapter like this;

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(myList, mCallback);
```

The RecyclerView adapter implements OnClickListener. In the OnClick method I called; 'mCallBack.onToolbarOptions("someTitle");'. And finally I made my MainActivity implement the method; 'implements myFragment.onItemsSelected' and I added the following code to it also;

```
@Override
public void onToolbarOptions(String title) {
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
}
```

With this, only the title is changed, but from this it is quite easy to make other changes to the toolbar, such as changing the menu items.

Comment: Make an interface to communicate with your `Activity` from a `Fragment`!

Comment: I was afraid that would be the way, I have no experience with interfaces, but I guess I have to dive in to it for this then. Thank you for your response :)

Comment: Let me try to check it for your question and show how you can access `View` in `Activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `Fragment` you make an Interface and a global variable like this:

```
OnItemsSelected mCallBack;

public interface OnItemsSelected {
    public void onToolbarOptions();
}
```

Then when in your `RecyclerView` items are selected or clicked you call:

```
mCallBack.onToolbarOptions();
```

In your `Activity` implement the Interface like this plus the method `onToolbarOptions()`:

```
public static class YourActivityName extends AppCompatActivity
    implements YourFragmentName.OnItemsSelected {

   public void onToolbarOptions(){
    // CHANGE YOUR TOOLBAR HERE
   }

  //.....OTHER STUFFS IN YOUR ACTIVITY
}
```

Comment: I finally got it working now, thanks to you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, Have a nice time and **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: I also want to send a message from my MainActivity to myFragment but for some reason I cannot figure out how to do that. Do you know how?

Comment: In that case you will have to use a `Bundle` and `setArguments`. Actually that is also explained in the Android Documentation Training about everything on how to make communications between a `Fragment` and its `Activity` see here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html